# Unable to add check constraint in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgesql.

I have already created a database and table. However in one of the table I want to add a constraint but it is not working. I wanted to set the value in column `is_official` to only T or F.

```
ALTER TABLE countrylanguage
ALTER COLUMN is_official 
ADD CONSTRAINT conchk 
CHECK (is_official IN ('T','F'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A check constraint is not defined on a column, but on the table. So the `alter column` part is invalid when you try to define a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE countrylanguage
  ADD CONSTRAINT conchk CHECK (is_official IN ('T','F'));
```

---

However, it would be better to define the column `is_official` as `boolean` rather than a `text` (or `varchar`)  with a check constraint on it to mimic a true `boolean` column.